# Nav Bar Fading Out and back In

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navbar

I am trying to create and effect with the nav bar. Right now I have a cover photo covering the entire page and when scrolling it will create a parallax effect revealing the content of the page. I would like the nav bar to lower in opacity as you scroll down, still remaining static, and once the cover photo is fully scrolled over and content covers the whole page, the nav bar (almost different looking too) fades back in and remains static again. Unfortunately I cannot find an example website to show. If anyone can help with this effect, Id be greatly appreciated. This is what I have so far.

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function(e) {
  $('#nav').css('opacity', ($(document).scrollTop() / 50000));
  var st = $(window).scrollTop();


  $('header').css({
    'background-position-y': 0 + (st * .77) + "px"
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #F9F9F9;
}
#page-wrap {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 1366px;
  max-width: 2048px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 100%;
}
header {
  background: url('../images/cover6.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  height: 1000px;
}
.nav_container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav_container nav {
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  background: #fff;
  width: 2048px;
  height: 85px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrap">
  <header>
    <div class="nav_container">
      <nav id="nav">Nav</nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="main">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example you may be able to modify to your tastes.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6kkzjw10/1/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<div id="bg"></div><!-- background image, allows opacity -->
<div class="nav_container">
    <nav id="nav">The NAV menu goes here and is rather wide</nav>
</div>
<div id="page-wrap">
    <div id="main">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#bg{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-image:url('http://placekitten.com/g/300/200');background-size:cover;opacity:0.3;}
#page-wrap{position:relative;width:100%;height:1500px;}
#main{height:1500px;width:80%;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;padding-top:200px;color:blue;}
.nav_container {position:fixed;left:0;bottom:0;width:100%;height:85px;}
#nav {width:100%;height:100%;text-align:center;color:yellow;font-size:2em;text-shadow:1px 1px 5px black;background:url(http://placekitten.com/g/500/80);}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('scroll', function (e) {

    var xx = 1 - ($(window).scrollTop() / 500);
    if (xx > 0) $('.nav_container').css('opacity', xx);
    else $('.nav_container').css('opacity', 1);

});
```